# jquery ajax and asp.net data entry form

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a pretty big data entry form which has many text fields which are dynamically added on the browser by the user. So i can not use server side controls such as asp:TextBox.

What would be the best way to submit the form and capture all the data on the server side?

I use asp.net 3.5 (web forms)

Answer (score 0):

1. register a hidden field in your asp net page
2. put your changes on client side into it.
3. load hidden field in postback
4. VALIDATE SOOO MUCH!

Comment: Thanks luke.. though i used hidden field the approach is little different.

Comment: what do you mean? was my answer in the right direction? You might be more specific so i could help you.

Comment: Luke, putting all in to a hidden field was not feasible as we needed the data in some structure and the input items were added in the browser with clone() method.. so we used a plugin to convert all the data on the form to json and set it to hidden field and on the server side we, capture the json data and use it... your answer would be enough for a simple page but in our case it was quite complex..!